# How to fix this Swift compiler error for onReceive method call?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have isolated this piece of code in a playground, using Xcode 11.1:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text(String(describing: name))
            TextField("First Name", text: $name)
        }.onReceive($name) { n in
            print("hey \(n)")
        }
    }
}

let uv = ContentView()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: uv)
```

This won't compile unless I leave out the onReceive part. The error message  is "Unable to infer closure type", but annotating the method only seems to give me other errors, not something that compiles.

How do I correct this snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can not delete this question, I will post an answer here myself.

The problem I had was that I tried to transform a `@State` into a `Publisher`, and `onReceive` requires a `Publisher` (as pointed out by @jfuellert). In a followup question (that I deleted), user @matt pointed me towards `@ObservedObject` for my use case.

One straightforward way to do what I was trying to do with `@State` here is to take advantage of the fact that each time the state var changes the body will be reevaluated:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        print("hey \(name)")
        return List {
            Text(String(describing: name))
            TextField("First Name", text: $name)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `onReceive` function takes in a Publisher type so you have to change `$name` to `name.publisher`.

```
var body: some View {
        List {
            Text(String(describing: name))
            TextField("First Name", text: $name)
        }.onReceive(name.publisher) { n in
            print("hey \(n)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I do have a followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645224/state-var-with-struct-has-no-publisher

Comment: This is actually something else: it is taking the publisher from a string, which then emits all of its characters on each change. I want a publisher from the state that publishes the new string in its entirety each time the state changes.